# Nearby Notification not showing for One Plus X

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, eddystone, google-nearby

Nearby Notifications doesn't show automatically on One Plus X device even with Nearby discoveries enabled (bluetooth, location and data are obviously enabled). What happens here is, if user manually go to Nearby Discoveries and scan there, then after exit, notifications start appearing.

I've tested it on Xiaomi and Motorola models and they don't seem to have this issue.

Is this a bug or some issue specifically in this model? Has anyone faced this issue in any other device?

Comment: Similar issue is being noticed for Samsung S7 edge.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, we're looking into it.

Comment: @TonyTran Thanks! This would be much helpful! Let me know if anything is needed from my end.

Comment: We're still actively looking at this and trying to figure out.  I'll post update as soon as I get them.

Comment: On the Nearby Notifications page (https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview), I found this: "Due to an issue that was discovered late in the development cycle, the Nearby Notifications feature will be temporarily muted for consumers beginning around September 21, 2016." The phrase "for consumers beginning around" is confusing. Does this mean new Android users or all users who haven't enabled Nearby Discoveries? Is the issue related? While I was all set to launch a business use case leveraging Nearby Notifications, this came as a shocking for me.

Comment: Avinash, are you still having issue with notification not showing up and then show up again? Please let me know the version of your Google Play Services so I can check on it.

Comment: I don't see this issue in One Plus X now. Notifications are shown properly. Surprisingly, the current version of Google Play Services is 9.8.77 for which notifications have been temporarily muted.

Comment: Thanks for verification that it's working again for your original issue.
About still seeing notifications in 9.8.77, it's probably because your device hasn't checked in yet.  Once it's checked in and get updated config, the notification will not appear.

Comment: The notification last seen yesterday is stuck there since last 12 hours. Probably the same bug you guys are working upon.

Comment: Yup, we want to fix that notification stuck issue.